# How to insert file in fileList?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backend

I am trying to perform an exercise in which I enter some images one by one in the first input file and I would like them to be saved automatically in the multiple input file to send the latter by post to an .php and upload them to the server but not how to do it.
I think it can be done because the input file multiple is a fileList and in the input file it is just a file but I do not know how to insert it automatically.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form action="preuba.php" method="POST">
  <input  name="file-input" id="file-input" type="file" />
  <output id="preview"></output>
  <br><br>

<input type="file" id="files" name="files[]" multiple />
<output id="list"></output>
<input type="submit" name="send">
</form>
<script>
 
function handleFileSelect(evt) {
    var files = evt.target.files; // FileList object

    // files is a FileList of File objects. List some properties.
    var output = [];
    for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {
        output.push('<li><strong>', escape(f.name), '</strong> (', f.type || 'n/a', ') - ',
            f.size, ' bytes, last modified: ',
            f.lastModifiedDate.toLocaleDateString(), '</li>');
    }
    document.getElementById('list').innerHTML = '<ul>' + output.join('') + '</ul>';
}

document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);

document.getElementById("file-input").onchange = function(e) {
    let reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function() {
        let preview = document.getElementById('list'),image = document.createElement('img');
        image.src = reader.result;
        preview.innerHTML += '';
        preview.append(image);
    };

    reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you want the user to be able to select a single file at a time, and each time a new file is selected, it gets added to a batch (rather than replacing the previous one), you would have to save off the file elements to their own array that the input does not replace.  Your logic would have to grab the files and push them to this array.  And later when you submit, you'd have to use that array for the data for the post.  You would also want to (most likely) provide a way for the user to remove files from that secondary array on the page, otherwise that could be a bad user experience.

Comment: that's what I'm trying to do but I can not add the object to the matrix of the second input

Comment: As far as I can tell, FileList are not allowed to be modified by javascript for security purposes.  If you want to keep a collection of files that later get uploaded, you would have to do something with ajax to perform those uploads, afaik.

Comment: I will send the files by ajax and store them in a matrix, then I will include the ajax file in my .php file to upload it to the server